# (rsErrorOpeningConnection) Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to deploy a report to the Reporting Services Server but keep running up against this error:

> An error occurred during client
>   rendering. An error has occurred
>   during report processing.
>   (rsProcessingAborted) Cannot create a
>   connection to data source
>   'dataSource1'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) Could not
>   obtain information about Windows NT
>   group/user 'DOMAIN\useradmin', error
>   code 0x5.

Here’s my situation: Everything is being ran using DOMAIN\useradmin and the report is using a remote database.

Reporting Services and SQL Server are both ran under DOMAIN\useradmin.  DOMAIN\useradmin is a windows AD login and is part of the server machine Administrators group.

My test report is using a data source model that in turn is using a data source that is connection to a database on a different SQL Server.  The data source is using **“Credentials stored securely in the report server”** with the options **“Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source”** and **“Impersonate the authenticated user after a connection has been made to the data source.”**

I am using the credentials of DOMAIN\useradmin that is the db owner of the remote database.

DOMAIN\useradmin is assigned the roles, **System Administrator, System User and Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder.**

So if everything is being run under an über AD account, why I am getting this Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DOMAIN\useradmin' error?

Under normal circumstances , an AD login with Publisher permissions will developing reports using a datasource model created by DOMAIN\useradmin but using one of the remote database’s users which is mapped from yet another AD login.

I ran the following statements and non errors were returned:

```
use master
go

xp_grantlogin 'DOMAIN\useradmin' 
go

xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\useradmin' 
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking “Impersonate the authenticated user after a connection has been made to the data source.”